# devstack install openstack-mitaka (ubuntu14.04)

Tags: openstack, devstack

Attempting to install DevStack on ubuntu14.04. I updated everything on ubuntu prior to installing DevStack. After ./stack.sh,I'm getting this error but all indications is that I have the Python components installed 
what should I do ?
 It is a bug??

erro log as following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could try to clone stable/mitaka branch and install devstack.

Newton release is still under development so might be buggy with keystone db.

./unstack.sh

./clean.sh

remove devstack checkout and also repo's download into /opt/stack/

git clone git://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git –b stable/mitaka

cd devstack

./stack.sh   ------>You can add local.conf before triggering this to automate installation process.